# move sprite from different computer

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp, xna, tcpclient

I am doing an assignment where I need to develop Robot environment using XNA and control the robot using c# TCP/IP Socket Technology from another computer. But when I inserted the server code into XNA it starts but game doesn't load.

```
 protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
{
//Server Settings
ipAddress = IPAddress.Parse("192.168.0.11");
myList = new TcpListener(ipAddress, 8000);
myList.Start();
s = myList.AcceptSocket();

b = new byte[100];
int? k = s.Receive(b);


// Allows the game to exit
if (GamePad.GetState(PlayerIndex.One).Buttons.Back == ButtonState.Pressed)
this.Exit();

if (Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.Right))
//if (k != null)
myRectangle.X += 3;
if (Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.Left))
myRectangle.X -= 3;
if (Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.Up))
myRectangle.Y -= 3;
if (Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.Down))
myRectangle.Y += 3;


//Screen Boundries
if (myRectangle.X <= 0)
myRectangle.X = 0;

if (myRectangle.X + myTexture.Width >= screenWidth)
myRectangle.X = screenWidth - myTexture.Width;

if (myRectangle.Y <= 0)
myRectangle.Y = 0;


s.Close();
myList.Stop();
base.Update(gameTime);
}
```

Any idea?????

Comment: What errors are you getting? Have you tried stepping through the code?

Comment: Yes. I have tried i am not getting any error but nothing happening

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm no genius on TCP... But making a new TCP listener everyframe? That could be a problem.

Add

```
ipAddress = IPAddress.Parse("192.168.0.11");
myList = new TcpListener(ipAddress, 8000);
myList.Start();
s = myList.AcceptSocket();
```

To your initialize()

and

```
s.Close();
myList.Stop();
```

to your UnloadContent() or dispose method.

You should also think about adding elapsed time to your movements, so it is the same speed on every computer.